# Is there a word for "concerned" that does not imply "worrying"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can be used in place of *concerned*, but that doesn't imply that something is wrong, or that the individual is worried?

For instance, the following sentence:

> A **concerned** parent will ask a child what happened during school that day.

means that the parent is worrying about the child, and may be afraid something had happened at school. Is there a different adjective to describe the parent that shows that they are asking because they are *interested* in what happened during the day, not *worried*.

Comment: What's wrong with *interested*?

Comment: Perhaps they're *caring* parents.

Comment: You might consider _involved_: "An involved parent knows their student's schedule, the classes they're taking, their teachers, and their grades." (D.P. King)

Comment: All the suggestions above are excellent. Just don't confuse anxious with eager. If you are looking forward to taking part in an activity, chances are you are eager to participate, not anxious. If you're dreading taking part in an activity, chances are you're anxious, not eager. All this to say, "Eager, proactive parents will ask a child what happened during school that day" is wordy, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the following:

> Caring parents will ask their child what happened during school that day.